Is there a way to display .chm files in WinUI3?
I have a user manual in the form of a .chm file and need a way to display it in my Winui3 app.
I've been trying to use a WebView2 control but either using .NavigateToString() or setting .Source of the WebView2 doesn't quite work.

You can decompile any CHM into a folder using hh.exe -decompile myChm.chm folderPath and then point a WebView2 at it.

You can create a HTML Help Executable process to display a .chm file.
Seen this,

The HTML Help ActiveX control is built into the Help Viewer so that
any navigational elements (such as a table of contents, index, or
full-text search) specified by the help author will be part of the
compiled help file that a user sees.

you may host the ActiveX control in your WinUI3 project but it's not easy. For an example which hosts MSRDP ActiveX control, see Question: is ActiveX Control support possible/planned for WinUI 3 ?
